# How do I remove the value of the settings for VSIX when I uninstall it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I have followed the steps under https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-user-settings-and-options?view=vs-2019 to create settings for my extension but seem after I uninstall and re-install the extension, the settings value still the one I configured before rather than the default value, do I doing this one in the wrong way or?
Can someone give some advice on that? Thanks!

Comment: Normally settings are kept between uninstall and reinstall. Is that a problem in your case?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Thanks for the information. Not a problem, just a data clean obsessive-compulsive disorder

Comment: Try to delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\Extensions`